# centos 7: sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.d/50-default.conf returns error

Tags: kernel, centos7, systemd, sysctl

I have rented container from OVH a while ago but last night all of a sudden my machine stopped responding on IP level... after reboot I have noticed the following

```
systemd-sysctl.service - Apply Kernel Variables 
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-sysctl.service; static 
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) 




sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.d/50-default.conf
```

produces:

```
sysctl: permission denied on key 'kernel.sysrq'
sysctl: permission denied on key 'kernel_core_uses_pid'
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter =1
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/fs/protected_hardlinks: No such file or directory 
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/fs/protected_symlinks: No such file or directory
```

Comment: can you post content of `/etc/sysctl.d/50-default.conf`? and are you `root` while running `sysctl` command?

Comment: Looks like kernel version related issue https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1084903

Comment: You can't change some sysctls inside a container. They can only be set on the host.